# How to put an Edittext with a button below that when I click, it recognizes if it's correct or wrong?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button, identify

My intention is to put an `Edittext`, and a `Button` below, and when the user put an specific word and click the button, the value is correct, and all the other different words are wrong.. How to identify it with codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
  btn.onClickListiner(this);

  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v == btn) {
   // check word
     String word = editText.getText().toString(); // don't forget "toString()" .
    // checking word below :

  }}
```